# jetty embedded jsp issues

Tags: java, jsp, embedded-jetty

I am trying to run a very simple java server with jetty embedded.
I am using gradle to compile it but for simplicity I'll just describe the way I am trying to start my process

```
start.bat
com
    test
        worktest
            Starter.class
            WebServer.class

./lib:
    asm-3.2.jar
    cglib-nodep-2.2.jar
    ecj-3.12.3.jar
    gentyref-1.2.0.jar
    gson-2.8.2.jar
    javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
    jetty-http-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
    jetty-io-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
    jetty-jsp-2.1-7.5.4.v20111024.jar
    jetty-security-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
    jetty-server-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
    jetty-servlet-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
    jetty-util-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
    jetty-webapp-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
    jetty-xml-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
    mockachino-0.6.2.jar
    objenesis-1.2.jar
    slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
    slf4j-simple-1.6.2.jar
    tomcat-api-9.0.5.jar
    tomcat-el-api-9.0.5.jar
    tomcat-jasper-9.0.5.jar
    tomcat-jasper-el-9.0.5.jar
    tomcat-jsp-api-9.0.5.jar
    tomcat-juli-9.0.5.jar
    tomcat-servlet-api-9.0.5.jar
    tomcat-util-9.0.5.jar
    tomcat-util-scan-9.0.5.jar

./web:
    index.jsp

./web/js:
    jquery-1.7.1.min.js
```

start.bat looks like this

```
cat start.bat
set JAVA_STARTER="com.test.worktest.Starter"
set CLASSPATH=".\lib\*;."
java -cp %CLASSPATH% %JAVA_STARTER%
```

The server starts just fine but when i try to access localhost:port I am getting

```
Problem accessing /index.jsp. Reason:

JSP support not configured
```

I am on jdk 9.0.1.

PART 2

Following up on the answer below, I have made a few changes to my gradle script. Got rid of not compatible deps.

I also figured out that asm3.0 was a dep for mockachino. It's now gone. At the moment I am looking like:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
  compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.25'
  runtime group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: '1.7.25'
  compile group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'jetty-http', version: '9.4.8.v20171121'
  compile group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'jetty-server', version: '9.4.8.v20171121'
  compile group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'jetty-servlet', version: '9.4.8.v20171121'
  compile group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'jetty-webapp', version: '9.4.8.v20171121'
  compile group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'apache-jsp', version: '9.4.8.v20171121'
  compile group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'jetty-annotations', version: '9.4.8.v20171121'
  compile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
  testCompile group: 'se.mockachino', name: 'mockachino', version: '0.6.2'
  testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

and my lib folder:

```
apache-el-8.5.23.jar
apache-jsp-8.5.23.jar
apache-jsp-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
asm-6.0.jar
asm-commons-6.0.jar
asm-tree-6.0.jar
ecj-3.12.3.jar
gson-2.8.2.jar
javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
jetty-annotations-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
jetty-http-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
jetty-io-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
jetty-jndi-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
jetty-plus-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
jetty-schemas-3.1.jar
jetty-security-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
jetty-server-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
jetty-servlet-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
jetty-util-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
jetty-webapp-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
jetty-xml-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar
```

When accessing the jsp I am still getting:

1. java.lang.IllegalStateException: No org.apache.tomcat.InstanceManager set in ServletContext
2. org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP

Code is [here](https://github.com/Riziero/flex)

I'll keep posting updates as I find things out.

Answer (score 2):

You have to setup JSP for Jetty, the mere existence of the JARs is insufficient.

The following JARs should be removed from your project.

```
jetty-jsp-2.1-7.5.4.v20111024.jar
tomcat-api-9.0.5.jar
tomcat-el-api-9.0.5.jar
tomcat-jasper-9.0.5.jar
tomcat-jasper-el-9.0.5.jar
tomcat-jsp-api-9.0.5.jar
tomcat-juli-9.0.5.jar
tomcat-servlet-api-9.0.5.jar
tomcat-util-9.0.5.jar
tomcat-util-scan-9.0.5.jar
```

`jetty-jsp` is not valid for Jetty 9.4.8.

The straight/normal/default Tomcat libraries are 100% incompatible within Jetty.

> **Important:** For success with JSP, Use a proper build system (choose one of the following: maven, ant+ivy, buildr, grails, grape, sbt, or leiningen).  Don't skip this, don't work around this, don't try to do it manually.

Use a proper `servlet-api` jar.

http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavax.servlet%7Cjavax.servlet-api%7C3.1.0%7Cjar

Remove `ecj-3.12.3.jar` if you are deploying to a JDK, or intend to use Java 1.7 (or newer) features within your JSPs.  By default, the JDK compiler will be used if present.  Don't forget to configure your desired source/target levels on the `JettyJspServlet` configuration.

Make sure you use a valid ASM jar for Jetty 9.4.8.

Remove this as it's incompatible:

```
asm-3.2.jar
```

Make sure you use the `jetty-annotations` artifact (and transient dependencies) from the `org.eclipse.jetty` group id, aligned with the same version as the rest of your jetty artifacts.

http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.eclipse.jetty%7Cjetty-annotations%7C9.4.8.v20171121%7Cjar

This will pull in the correct asm jars and appropriate dependencies needed for your JSP webapp.

You'll need the `apache-jsp` artifact (and transient dependencies) from the `org.eclipse.jetty` group id, aligned with the same version as the rest of your jetty artifacts.

http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.eclipse.jetty%7Capache-jsp%7C9.4.8.v20171121%7Cjar

This will pull in the correct JSP support libraries (and JSTL/EL) that you need.

Then you'll need to configure for JSP.

See the sample project at https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-jsp

Finally, some things you need to consider with JSP/JSTL/EL support:

- Don't bundle up in OSGi (the JSTL/EL/Standard libraries do not support this usage. mainly due to classloader expectations)
- Don't use Java 9+ JPMS modules (the JSTL/EL/Standard libraries do not support this usage, mainly due to classloader expectations, and resource url expecations)
- Don't create an uber jar (the JSTL/EL/Standard libraries do not support this)
- Don't repackage the JSTL jars in any way, they need to stay as the JSTL/EL/Standard jars, available on the filesystem.
- Don't create custom classloaders. (The JSTL/EL/Standard libraries expect a very narrow definition of a Classloader)

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I need to finish it up tomorrow but I've picked up some of your comments.

Consider that the code was given to me, it's very old and I am trying to put together some gradle scripts to cope with them.

If anyone wants to take a look: https://github.com/Riziero/flex

Comment: I'll mark this an answer. Biggest deal was to figure out which Jetty version I needed for the code. I just ended up using latest Jetty (9.4) and re-vamping my code.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to post this here as I was facing a similar issue after migrating a legacy app from tomcat to jetty. I got the `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No org.apache.tomcat.InstanceManager set in ServletContext` exception but not the other exception you mention. I feel this is the most appropriate place to post this considering this is the first post that shows when searching for that error.

After doing extensive research I came across [this thread](https://www.eclipse.org/lists/jetty-users/msg09304.html). As the thread shows, that error can be thrown when jetty is missing some modules. In this particular case the missing modules were `plus` and `annotations`.

Jetty modules can be enabled in a couple of different ways. For instance, you can add the `--add-to-start=<module-name1>,<module-name2>,…​etc.` parameter to your start command:

```
[mybase]$ java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar --add-to-start=server,deploy,http,jmx,stats,servlets,webapp,logging-log4j,apache-jsp,apache-jstl,plus,annotations
```

You can also do it programmatically by using the `addAfter` and `addBefore` functions. One thing to note here as that the order in which you add modules programmatically matters so be careful where you add them. Here is a sample snippet:

```
//Create the server
Server server = new Server(8080);

//Enable parsing of jndi-related parts of web.xml and jetty-env.xml
org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration.ClassList classlist = org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration.ClassList.setServerDefault(server);
classlist.addAfter("org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration", "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration", "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration");
classlist.addBefore("org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration", "org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration");
```

Another way to add them would be through XML files. Here's the contents of the jetty-provided `jetty-plus.xml` and `jetty-annotations.xml` files.

### jetty-plus.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">

<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">

  <!-- =========================================================== -->
  <!-- Add plus Configuring classes to all webapps for this Server -->
  <!-- =========================================================== -->
  <Call class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration$ClassList" name="setServerDefault">
    <Arg><Ref refid="Server" /></Arg>
    <Call name="addAfter">
      <Arg name="afterClass">org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration</Arg>
      <Arg>
        <Array type="String">
          <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration</Item>
          <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration</Item>
        </Array>
      </Arg>
    </Call>
  </Call>

</Configure>
```

### jetty-annotations.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">

<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
  <!-- =========================================================== -->
  <!-- Add annotation Configuring classes to all webapps for this Server -->
  <!-- =========================================================== -->
  <Call class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration$ClassList" name="setServerDefault">
    <Arg><Ref refid="Server" /></Arg>
    <Call name="addBefore">
      <Arg name="beforeClass">org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration</Arg>
      <Arg>
        <Array type="String">
          <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration</Item>
        </Array>
      </Arg>
    </Call>
  </Call>

</Configure>
```

These XML files are used when you add them with the parameter option or you can also use them by enabling the respective modules through a `start.ini` file by adding modules with `--module=<module-name>`.

Hope this helps someone.

### References:

- [Jetty: The Definitive Reference](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-9/index.html)